# Help with Relations and Functions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I'm currently doing work on discrete mathematics in my free time and am having some difficulties with understanding some questions pertaining to Relations and Functions. To be specific, I'm stuck on the following practice question:

```
We have a relation R on Z+ defined as follows:
mRn if and only if m|n.
a. Explain why the relation R is not a function.
b. Determine the set A = {m ∈ Z|mR52} and give its cardinality |A|.
```

How would I go about finding the results of A and B to satisfy the relations? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Don't you mean $\mathbb Z$  instead of $\mathbb Z +12$?

Comment: Can you please explain what is meant by "Z + 12 pts."  Perhaps $\mathbb{Z}^+$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ or is it $\mathbb{Z}\cup \{a,b,\dots, l\}$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

A relation is functional only if the following holds:
$$\forall x,y_1,y_2 \in R(xRy_1 \wedge xRy_2) \Rightarrow y_1 = y_2$$

Answer (score 0):

a) The definition of a function relationship, xRy if you use their notation, is that each x has only one related y.  If the relation is m|n, do any of the m have more than one n related to it?  What is y if 3Ry?  Is there more than one?

[Not really hint.  If we used the common f(x) notations would f(n) = m s.t. n|m even make sense?  What is f(3)?]

b) The set is all m that divide 52.  How many are there and what are they?

Comment: So would the cardinality be 6 because (1,2,4,13,26,52) are all divisors of 52?

Comment: Yes. Yes, it would.

Comment: Also, for proving that it isn't a function would I say that y can be both 6 & 9 when x=3? Would that disqualify it from being a function because there are multiple possible pointers?

Comment: Exactly!  *That* is what defines a function from just a bunch of pairs of numbers.

Comment: It's still a *relationship*.  There can be relationships that aren't functions.  But a function is one where there first term (the input) has only one possible second term.  I'm not familiar with what the precise terminology in your course is about "pointers" so I don't feel comfortable saying "A function only has a single pointer" because I'm not certain what the definition of "pointer" is.  But that is the general idea.